# Creating a lifetime scope in Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Lets say during runtime I create an object, that will hold several IDisposables. As far as I understood it would be good practice to create a lifetime scope for that object, so that all its disposables will get cleaned up automatically.

But how exactly do I create the scope? Doesn't that require to pass the container around or make it a global variable?
Also: when/how would I end the lifetime scope?

Here's how my classes look now, without the scope:

```
internal class DocumentManager
{
    private readonly List<Document> mDocuments; 

    private readonly Func<Document> mDocumentFactory;

    public DocumentManager(Func<Document> documentFactory)
    {
      mDocumentFactory = documentFactory;
      mDocuments = new List<Document>();
    }

    public void AddDocument()
    {
      mDocuments.Add(mDocumentFactory.Invoke());
    }

    public void CloseAllDocuments()
    {
      mDocuments.Clear(); // -> Memory leak!
    }
}

internal class Document
{
    private List<NativeResource> mNativeResources;

    public Document(Func<NativeResource> nativeResourceFactory)
    {
      // Create some native resources. They will need to be disposed when this object dies?
      mNativeResources = new List<NativeResource>();
      mNativeResources.Add(mNativeResourceFactory.Invoke());
      mNativeResources.Add(mNativeResourceFactory.Invoke());
      mNativeResources.Add(mNativeResourceFactory.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the solution myself:
Instead of creating Documents, I simply changed my factory to produce `Owned<Document>`. These can be disposed and take all native resources they resolved with them.

Really simple. Thank's Autofac :-)